# Swagger UI to show Map example in XML

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

Hi I have the following schema, which contains a map of string and I have included some examples. The JSON display works but XML display not. Is there a way to workaround this?

```
paths:
  /somePath:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/SomeMap'
            application/xml:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/SomeMap'
components:
  schemas:
    SomeMap:
      type: object
      additionalProperties:
        type: string
      example:
        'key_1': 'value_1'
        'key_2': 'value_2'
        'key_3': 'value_3'
```

Output in JSON:

```
{
  "key_1": "value_1",
  "key_2": "value_2",
  "key_3": "value_3"
}
```

Output in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SomeMap>
    <additionalProp>string</additionalProp>
</SomeMap>
```

Expected output in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SomeMap>
    <key_1>value_1</key_1>
    <key_2>value_2</key_2>
    <key_3>value_3</key_3>
</SomeMap>
```

Using Swagger 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the XML example as a response example instead:

```yaml
paths:
  /somePath:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/SomeMap'
            application/xml:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/SomeMap'
              example: |
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <SomeMap>
                  <key_1>value_1</key_1>
                  <key_2>value_2</key_2>
                  <key_3>value_3</key_3>
                </SomeMap>
```

Comment: Thank you. I can see how this work. But this also means I will have to provide the whole XML response when I have other components (compare to having each individual example in the schema)?

Comment: Feel free to open an issue in Swagger UI's issue tracker https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues

Comment: So I take it as there is no other workaround at the moment then. Thanks for trying to help, but I can see the Swagger UI github even has issues from 2 years ago, that is not going to help :)